# How to get all open file handles in kernel space code?

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems

I want to write the code in kernel space to find all open file handles in the system and the `process id` which holdes those handles.

In user space we can do it using the utility "`lsof`". Similarly, i want the same in kernel space.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service

Comment: I need the concept or method to get all the open file handles from kernel space

Answer (score 2):

What's so great about Linux Kernel is that it's open source. If you want to understand how to implement something that is similar to `lsof` why not inspecting its' source code (I suggest [the following implementation, from Android 4.2.2 source tree](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/toolbox/lsof.c), at it is simplified and easier to understand) or `strace`ing it to understand how the magic happens?

If you'll do so, at some point you'll encounter the following line

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/<PID>/fd", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC)
```

Which will hint you that for each PID that is running, `procfs` is able to print information about all open file descriptors that this process holds. Therefore, [this](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/fs/proc/fd.c) is where I would start my research and journey through the code.